# Using jQuery .find() to traverse child textboxes, and mark them as checked, in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, find

I'm trying to use jQuery to find any child check boxes, and mark them as checked when a parent checkbox has been checked. These checkboxes are in nested UL's. The class chkIssue indicates a parent checkbox.

I haven't had much luck using the find function.

```
$(".chkIssue").click( function() {
        alert($(this).find("input:checkbox").attr('name'));
        $(this).find("input:checkbox").attr('checked','checked');
});
```

The event listener is working fine, but the .find function does not appear to be. I have ~20 nested checkboxes, but only get one alert, and a name value that is undefined.

Any immediate thoughts?

Comment: Can we see the html markup or the relevant portion of it?

Comment: The HTML was pretty complex, as I'm using heavily nested lists that hold a good chunk of data. These solutions didn't resolve the problem, but I found an alternative method of just setting another attribute on the child text boxes to "key" with an attribute on the parent, and then just did a .each iteration on every checkbox on the page to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$.each()`:

```
$(this).find("input:checkbox").each(function(i, cbox){
   $(cbox).attr('checked',1);
});
```

Comment: Also, can you show us a sample of your markup structure? May be easier to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `find` within a checkbox as it won't have checkbox descendents. Also use prop() method for jQuery version >=1.6

Following will toggle the other checkboxes on/off. Also assumes from your description that "chkIssue" is a checkbox,original description is ambiguous

```
$(".chkIssue").change( function() {
    var checked=this.checked;                           
    $('#otherCheckboxesMainContainer').find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', checked);                     

});
```